# How to get customized "from address" in Grails Email service

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, sendmail

I have question regarding Email service "from" address. I want to show a name say XYZ instead of XYZ@abc.com. I tried to have it have a string "XYZ" in from but i was getting a mailsend exception.

```
mailService.sendMail{
                from "XYZ"
                to "abc@123.com"
                subject "HI"
                body "How ru?"
            }
```

The Exception is:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException:
  Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 
    553 5.5.4 <XYZ>... Domain name required for sender address XYZ.
```

Is there any way to have a alias name instead of from address in the from coloumn of the mail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Complete guess, but does it work if you do:

```
mailService.sendMail{
  from "XYZ <XYZ@abc.com>"
  to "abc@123.com"
  subject "HI"
  body "How ru?"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ....Will try that...Any ways if I have it as from "XYZ" it still works fine on my local....But on our server SMTP host is excepting a domain...will try out your approach and see if it works....

Comment: The underlying [Spring implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setFrom%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) allows you to specify the personal name for a from address, but it looks like this isn't exposed by the [grails mail plugin](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/mail/MailMessageBuilder.groovy). Hopefully this workaround works...

Comment: Yes ...that works fine ...but it still exposes the domain name to receiver ....I wanted to hide the domain name...... in the from its showing like......Support<abc@xyz.com>....

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to get much better...  Also, the display of that is down to the email client, so you have little or no control...  Send an email to a gmail address...it should hide the actual address for example in the inbox...  Someone else may know better, but I am out of better ideas ;-)

Comment: Thats fine...I was looking through the documentation and I think this the thing we can have....